# What to do with the [escript] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently there are only **14** questions tagged with [escript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escript). Acording to the tag description, it's a script language designed for Eclipse:

> eScript is designed to describe the various steps in adding support
>   for a new programming language to Eclipse. The idea behind eScript is
>   that someone can implement an Eclipse plug-in by using a simple script
>   language instead of using a sometimes complicated and confusing
>   combination of XML and Java. For more details, see this link :
>   http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_eScript%3F

However, only 1 out of the 14 questions is related to Eclipse. Most of them (11) are about *Siebel eScript*, a JavaScript dialect used in Oracle's Siebel CRM.

What should we do with the tag?

- Edit the description so it states that *eScript* may refer to a JavaScript dialect used in Siebel CRM, or a script language used in Eclipse.
- Split it in `Siebel-eScript` and `Eclipse-eScript`.
- Remove it... it only has 14 questions anyway.

I guess the right action would be editing the description, but I don't know if it's really useful keeping a tag with just 14 questions, specially when it's somehow ambiguous and it doesn't add much value. If you have a question about Siebel eScript, you're most likely going to search for Siebel, not eScript...

Comment: I would vote for making `siebel-escript` and dropping the the other use.  There has only be one question about eScript and that was 2 years ago.  The Eclipse tag should be enough.

Comment: @JasonMArcher I would vote for such an answer.